# Know the type of Laravel errors

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I need to know some tips to know the source of errors in Laravel for example sometimes it only shows this message "Whoops, looks like something went wrong" and you don't know the type of error. It must be a trick allowing you to know your error. Thanks

Comment: Open your error log (**storage/logs/laravel.log**).

Comment: Thanks a lot it shows the type of error

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to edititing the **.env**?

```
APP_NAME=MyApp
APP_ENV=local
APP_KEY= some key
APP_DEBUG=true 
APP_LOG_LEVEL=debug
```

If you turn app debug to true, you should be able to see errors.

Comment: I already done it but it still shows Whoops, looks like something went wrong.

Comment: In my case I'm trying to immerge two laravel projects, i placed one view and it's layout and route from the first project to the second one and it shows the message "Whoops, looks like something went wrong."